# Date datatype updation in laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-5

i am updating data posted from form.
one of the column is of datatime datatype in mysql.

All the data is updating except the Datetime column.

My code is as below

```
DB::table('CANDIDATE')
->where('CANDIDATEID',$ID)
->update(
        [
        'fname'=>$fname
        ,'mname'=>$mname
        ,'lname'=>$lname
        ,'genderid'=>$GENDERID
        ,'dob'=>$dob
        ,'address'=>$address
        ,'city'=>$city
        ,'pinno'=>$pinno
        ,'statesid'=>$STATESID
        ,'countryid'=>$COUNTRYID
        ,'contactno'=>$contactno
        ,'industryprtid'=>$INDUSTRYPRTID
        ,'cur_prof_titl'=>$cur_prof_titl
        ,'skills'=>$skills
        ,'certificate'=>$certificate
        ,'emp_typeid'=>$EMPTYPEID
        ,'experienceid'=>$EXPERIENCEID
        ,'educationid'=>$EDUCATIONID
        ,'edu_major'=>$edu_major
        ,'other_detail'=>$other_detail
        ,'mainobj'=>$mainobj
        ,'relocate'=>$relocate
        ,'sal_rngid'=>$sal_rngid
        ]

);
```

What is wrong in the code.

Comment: Which column is the DateTime column? And what is in the parameter that you are using for that column?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - DOB( Date of Birth) is the Datetime Column. also I have removed the fname but still the DOB column is not working

Comment: What data type do you use for `dob` and what value do you pass?

Comment: I have used Datetime datatype and date value i want to pass

Comment: But WHAT VALUE are you passing in `$dob`

Comment: I am passing a date value i.e. 2017/02/13

Comment: Thanks shukshin.ivan, i changed my datatype from datetime to date and i am able to save the data.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not set the timestamps when you're using the fluent builder instead of using Eloquent. So you'll need a model for this.

Fluent builder will not set timestamps

```
DB::table('CANDIDATE')
    ->where('CANDIDATEID', $ID)
    ->update(
    // ...
```

Eloquent model will:

```
<?php namespace App\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model
{
    // Model foo here
}
```

And then use:

```
App\Namespace\Candidate::where('CANDIDATEID, $ID)
    ->update(
    // ...
```

Given that you do have the default laravel timestamp columns available in your table. (created_at, updated_at).

---

Unrelated, but worth mentioning:

If/when possible, check your naming convention, it will be easier to follow the Laravel naming convention for table and column names (e.g. use `candidates` as table name and `candidate_id` for column names.)